# "Double Eval" XPath expression has a trailing semicolon... Giving me fits

Tags: xml, xpath, infopath

Running into trailing semicolon issues while using a "Double Eval" XPath expression in conjunction with MS InfoPath to capture the contents of repeating structures. I need to eliminate the trailing semicolon from the result. Here is the expression:

`eval(eval(Repeater, 'concat(my:Node1DropDown, ";")'), "..")`

The results of the above expression can be seen in "Node1Eval" in the below XML. The expression would be great except for the trailing semicolon in the result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?mso-infoPathSolution solutionVersion="1.0.0.4" productVersion="14.0.0" PIVersion="1.0.0.0" href="file:///C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\Chris\Local%20Settings\Application%20Data\Microsoft\InfoPath\Designer3\e2c7e5c6af2049e9\manifest.xsf" ?><?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.2"?>
<my:myFields xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-08-28T16:45:10" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003" xml:lang="en-us">
<my:Master_Section>
    <my:group2>
        <my:Repeater>
            <my:Node1DropDown>Lasers</my:Node1DropDown>
            <my:Node2DropDown>Lemon</my:Node2DropDown>
        </my:Repeater>
        <my:Repeater>
            <my:Node1DropDown>Sharks</my:Node1DropDown>
            <my:Node2DropDown>Apple</my:Node2DropDown>
        </my:Repeater><my:Repeater>
            <my:Node1DropDown>Monkeys</my:Node1DropDown>
            <my:Node2DropDown>Lemon</my:Node2DropDown>
        </my:Repeater>
    </my:group2>
    <my:Node1Eval>Lasers;Sharks;Monkeys;</my:Node1Eval>
    <my:Node2Eval>Lemon;Apple;Lemon;</my:Node2Eval>
</my:Master_Section>
</my:myFields>
```

I would guess that the addition of some logic relating to the position of the returned item could help eliminate the trailing semicolon.

The *real* crux of the issue is that the semi-colon is *always* there; I need the `Node1Eval` field to be **empty** until it actually has a value to display. If not then it will mess with a `[text()]` XPath expression test I am trying to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denoting your

> eval(eval(Repeater, 'concat(my:Node1DropDown, ";")'), "..")

by **X**, it would be

> substring(**X**, 1, string-length(**X**) - 1)

giving eventually

> substring(eval(eval(Repeater, 'concat(my:Node1DropDown, ";")'), "..");
>   1, string-length(eval(eval(Repeater, 'concat(my:Node1DropDown, ";")'),
>   "..")) - 1)

**Update:**
If you search by "**substring(eval(eval(**", you can confirm that it is quite frequently used for repeating controls in Infopath, for ex., [this discussion](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/t/8411.aspx?PageIndex=1)

> I need the Node1Eval field to be empty until it actually has a value
>   to display

In Infopath Designer, on your rule action (or default value), wherever you insert and edit your Xpath expression, press **fx** > double-click on **Repeater** > press **Filter data...** button and insert whtever condition you wish.
For the case, of Node1DropDown being non-blank, it will probably  result in

```
eval(eval(Repeater[Node1DropDown != ""], 'concat(my:Node1DropDown, ";")'), "..")
```

Comment: Gennady, thanks! Works great. Only note is that InfoPath likes commas in the substring function - `substring(X, 1, string-length(X) - 1)` But it works great! Thanks!

Comment: I believe I've checked that both commas and semi-colons work both in substring() and concat() in Infopath 2010. One should not mix them though

Comment: Hmm - I am using a 2007 template, so perhaps that is why it didn't like the semi-colons? As soon as I switched them to commas it took. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've Changed my post (from semicolons to commas in XPath expressios)